# How to query all campaigns related to an Account

Tags: account, campaign

I see in the related lists of Account has Campaign section. However, in my understanding, Campaign doesn't have child relationship with Account object. How can I query all Campaigns related to an Account? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query to get all campaigns related to the account.

Query:

```
SELECT Campaign.Name, Campaign.StartDate, Campaign.EndDate, Campaign.Status FROM CampaignMember WHERE (Contact.AccountId = 'ACCOUNT_ID')
```

**Campaign** is just a related list in the account page layout and always campaigns are related to either Lead or Contact objects.

Refer to the [Reveal Relationships Between Accounts and Campaigns](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_pardot_account_campaign_related_lists.htm&release=224&type=5)

**CampaignMember**:

> Represents the association between a campaign and either a lead or a
> contact.

Refer to the [CampaignMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm)

Comment: N.B. You can also [enable Accounts to be CampaignMembers](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.campaigns_account_campaign_member.htm&type=5) with optional feature